How to copy Numpy arrays into C++ arrays quickly
I'm trying to create an circular buffer for images in C++ that receives the images as Numpy arrays.  I can correctly store the images and retrieve them, but it's crazy slow, 100's of times slower than just doing it all in Python.  I'm learning C++, but I'm not sure how to speed this up.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Edit:  I'm using Visual Studio and have enabled all of the speed optimizations, however they didn't seem to have any effect at all.
void Buffer::do_nothing(py::array_t<uint8_t> &input_array, int time_code, string time_stamp) {
    auto view = input_array.unchecked<3>();

    if ((view.shape(0) != Buffer::frame_height) || (view.shape(1) != Buffer::frame_width) || (view.shape(2) != 3)) {
        cout << "Error: Incorrect incoming array size\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    const int channels = view.shape(2);
    const int height = view.shape(0);
    const int width = view.shape(1);

    int t;

    for (int i = 0; i < channels; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < width; k++) {
                
                Buffer::frames[(Buffer::high * Buffer::frame_size) + (Buffer::channel_size * i) + (j * Buffer::frame_width) + k] = view(j, k, i);
            }
        }
    }

}

Buffer::frames is an array initialized by:
Buffer::frames = new uint8_t[circ_buffer_size * frame_height * frame_width * 3];

For comparison, in Python I created a list of [None] * circ_buffer_size then assign the frame to one of the list elements.
import numpy as np
import time

circ_buffer_size = 10
framebuffer = [None] * circ_buffer_size
test_array = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(1080,1920, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

start = time.time()
for i in range(200):
    framebuffer[i % circ_buffer_size] = test_array

print(f"Elapsed: {time.time() - start}")


Elapsed: 0.0030002593994140625

By comparison, my C++ / Pybind11 example takes 1.08 seconds.

First question when it concerns speed and C++: did you enable optimizations?

@Botje VS speed optimizations are enabled.

Let me rephrase the question: Are you compiling in debug mode or in release mode?

Both have the same effect.  Copying an image (1080, 1920, 3) takes seconds.  Doing it in straight Python using lists takes <0.01

Are you copying the lists in python as reference or are you doing a deep copy?

@Botje - I did fix the release mode settings and got my 200 iteration test down to about 1 second.  Still very slow.

@Joel - I've updated my question to show what I'm doing in Python.

That just takes 200 references to the same numpy array. To even be a remotely fair comparison you should do test_array.copy().

200 iterations per second is 1.2GB/s. That's not bad for the terrible memory access pattern you're using.

What would be a better memory access pattern then?  That's what I'm trying to improve.

For starters .. why did you swap the dimensions from (height, width, channel) to (channel, height, width)? Did you make ask numpy for a contiguous memory buffer? If the reshaping was accidental and you can make the numpy array contiguous, why not skip the copy and use the address underlying the array directly?

framebuffer[i % circ_buffer_size] = test_array This appears to be storing a reference to test_array inside of framebuffer. It's not copying the array - only a reference to it. It would be more analogous to what you're doing in C++ if you declared framebuffer as an ndarray of size (circ_buffer_size, height, width, 3), and then did framebuffer[i % circ_buffer_size] = test_array.

To me it looks like you are doing 10801920 3, so O(N^3), assignments in C++ and in Python you are only assigning 200 references of test_array to framebuffer.
